# Volley perform too many uncontrolled retries

Tags: android, android-volley

I have a serious problem.

I have a small app for a restaurant to manage the creation of orders, update, and so. Waiters use an android tablet to serve to the customers.

The thing is that since a week or so, I realized that tickets tend to duplicate items. After some research and diving into the logs, I realized that many times, when I call an AsyncTask to make a request to the server, it doesn't send ONE request, it sends several requests instead. 
For that reason, if I call the "addItemToOrder" service four times, it will add four items instead of just one.

Here is my code. This is a "generic GET Async Task" that I call. It has an url, it may or not has some parameters, and it just creates a volley request that sends to the server. As you can see, it has 0 retries and, before you can ask, I just made sure that this AT is not being called more than once:

```
package es.vdevelop.tpvmobile.asynctask;

import android.content.Context;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.android.volley.DefaultRetryPolicy;
import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;
import com.bugfender.sdk.Bugfender;

import org.json.JSONException;

import java.lang.ref.WeakReference;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import es.vdevelop.tpvmobile.Constants;
import es.vdevelop.tpvmobile.ErrorHelper;
import es.vdevelop.tpvmobile.FunctionsHelper;


abstract class GenericGetAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    private static final String TAG = "DEBUG GenericGetAT";

    Handler h;
    WeakReference<Context> context;

    String auxURL;
    HashMap<String, String> postParams;
    String query;

    GenericGetAsyncTask(WeakReference<Context> context, Handler h) {
        this.auxURL = "";
        this.context = context;
        this.h = h;
        this.postParams = new HashMap<>();
        this.query = "";
    }


    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(final Void... params) {
        if (!FunctionsHelper.isConnected(context.get())) {
            h.sendEmptyMessage(ErrorHelper.HANDLER_NO_INTERNET_ERROR);
            Bugfender.d(TAG, "No internet connection");
            ErrorHelper.mostrarError(context.get(), ErrorHelper.HANDLER_NO_INTERNET_ERROR, TAG);
            return null;
        }

        String urlParcial = Constants.getUrl(context.get());
        if (urlParcial.equals("")) {
            h.sendEmptyMessage(ErrorHelper.HANDLER_FALTA_URL);
            Bugfender.d(TAG, "Falta url");
            ErrorHelper.mostrarError(context.get(), ErrorHelper.HANDLER_URL_INCORRECTA, TAG);
            return null;
        }


        int metodo;
        String url;
        if (query == null || query.equals("")) {
            url = urlParcial + this.auxURL;
            metodo = Request.Method.POST;
        } else {
            url = urlParcial + this.auxURL + "?" + this.query;
            metodo = Request.Method.GET;
        }
        Bugfender.d(TAG, "url -> " + url);


        final RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context.get());
        final StringRequest request = new StringRequest(metodo, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {

            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                try {
                    onResultRetrieved(response);
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    Bugfender.d(TAG, "Hubo un error de json en onResponse -> " + e.toString());
                    h.sendEmptyMessage(ErrorHelper.HANDLER_RESPUESTA_INCORRECTA);
                    ErrorHelper.mostrarError(context.get(), ErrorHelper.HANDLER_JSON, TAG);
                }
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Bugfender.d(TAG, "Error recibido del servidor -> " + error.toString());
                ErrorHelper.mostrarError(context.get(), ErrorHelper.HANDLER_RESPUESTA_INCORRECTA, TAG);
                Toast.makeText(context.get(), "Error realizando llamada http -> " + error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                h.sendEmptyMessage(ErrorHelper.HANDLER_ERROR);
            }
        }) {
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
                return postParams;
            }

            @Override
            public Priority getPriority() {
                return Priority.IMMEDIATE;
            }
        };
        request.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(2000, 0, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));

        queue.add(request);
        return null;
    }


    protected abstract void onResultRetrieved(String result) throws JSONException;
}
```

After that, then I just have to inherit from this generic AT with just some bit of code to make a simple request, just as you can see here in this "UpdateTicketAT":

```
package es.vdevelop.tpvmobile.asynctask;

import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Handler;

import com.bugfender.sdk.Bugfender;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.lang.ref.WeakReference;

import es.vdevelop.tpvmobile.Constants;
import es.vdevelop.tpvmobile.ErrorHelper;
import es.vdevelop.tpvmobile.Functions;


public class UpdateTicketAsyncTask extends GenericGetAsyncTask {

    private static final String TAG = "DEBUG UpdateTicketAT";

    public UpdateTicketAsyncTask(WeakReference<Context> context, Handler h, String json) {
        super(context, h);
        this.auxURL = "actualizar_ticket.php";
        this.postParams.put("ticket", json);
        Bugfender.d(TAG, "Ticket que vamos a enviar -> " + json);
    }


    @Override
    protected void onResultRetrieved(String response) throws JSONException {
        Bugfender.d(TAG, "Respuesta obtenida del servidor -> " + response);
        JSONObject result = new JSONObject(response);
        int codigo = result.getInt("codigo");
        if (codigo == 0) {
            h.sendEmptyMessage(Constants.handlerOk);
            Bugfender.d(TAG, "Ticket actualizado correctamente");
        } else {
            h.sendEmptyMessage(Constants.handlerError);
            ErrorHelper.mostrarError(context.get(), codigo, TAG);
        }
    }
}
```

I can't find out what is happening here. Am I doing something wrong?

One important thing is that the calls to the server may not be all made in a row. I mean, I make a request, I get the response, and maybe a minute or two later, the request is made again!

I just can be aware of this by looking into the server logs..

I don't know what's happening here..

Anyway, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I can see two ways to answer your question or not:

First: i don`t like your "0" in your DefaultRetryPolicy line, try to put some like this:

**jsonObjectRequest.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(TIMEOUT_SERVICE,
        DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));**

The first parameter is timeout, second is max retries (yes i know, you know that but check that is 1) and the last one is DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT ( again i know, blah blah, but check that is 1.0f) or put literal.

**jsonObjectRequest.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(TIMEOUT_SERVICE,
        1, 1.0f));**

Second: Can you only set more time in your time out.

I hope this help you.

Comment: This doesn't solve my problem. I've already tried with several retries, 1 retry, 0 retries and even -1 as it is suggested in another stackoverflow thread and it keeps happening. Thanks anyway for your help, but that's not the problem.. :(

Comment: Hello again! why are you using asynctask? Volley are asynchronous, if you try without async task, only the request with volley. Maybe there it´s the problem :)